# QWidget's minimumSize vs minimumSizeHint

Tags: qt, layout, qwidget

Qt's widgets have 2 properties determining how small they can be:

- [minimumSizeHint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop)
- [minimumSize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop)

Now their basic difference seems clear enough: `minimumSize` restricts what size the widget can actually have, and Qt won't allow setting the size smaller. It also overrides `minimumSizeHint`, if set. And then `minimumSizeHint` is only used by layouts, which won't resize the widget smaller than that when resizing its contents.

Now I was implementing a custom widget, no problems there, and I started wondering about this.

**Question**: why would you ever want to use `mininumSizeHint` at all? What is the scenario, where you have to, or want to use it instead of just always using `minimumSize`? Why does `minimumSizeHint` exist?

(And if answer is "yeah, `sizeHint` is enough for everything", that's fine.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main difference is that `minimumSize` can be changed by any other object at any time, whether you like it or not, as all QWidgets have a public `setMinimumSize()` function; whereas your widget alone controls what is returned by `minimumSizeHint()`.

As an implementer of a custom widget, you always want to override `minimumSizeHint()` if your widget has a minimum size that you think should usually be respected. This is what the built-in Qt widgets do.